# Overleaf problem fetching images from github

Tags: overleaf

I do not know where to post this so feel free to move it around if it is in the wrong place.

I have some pictures saved in a public github repository and i want overleaf to fetch them.
After giving the path to the github repo (1st pic) it seems to me that it gets the image (2nd pic) but in reality it does not (3rd pic).
Any idea why it does that?

[image]

[image: Image looks available urra!]

[image: Image is not available]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at a github link such as

https://github.com/w3c/mathml/blob/main/image/braids.png

You see it's not a png but a web page, and if you upload that url to overleaf and download the project, you will see it has received a JSON file. This is under the control of github, not overleaf.

Easiest way (without the github sync paid-for option) is to run github-pages, the above file is served as an image from

https://w3c.github.io/mathml/#example

as

https://w3c.github.io/mathml/image/braids.png

and that works:

[image]